$\lambda_i,i=1,2,...,n$(pairwise different) are not eigenvalues of $T$.Prove that there exist $c_i,i=1,2...,n,s.t. \sum c_i(T-\lambda_iE)^{-1} =E$
$T$ is a linear transformation on some linear space V,where V is a linear space with dimension n on a number domain $F$.$\lambda_i \in F,i=1,2,...,n$(pairwise different) are not eigenvalues of $T$.
Prove that there exist $c_i \in F,i=1,2...,n,s.t. \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i(T-\lambda_iE)^{-1} =E$
($E$ is the identity transformation).
As $x-\lambda_i$ is relatively prime to eigenpolynomial of $T$,we can easily obtain that $(T-\lambda_iE)^{-1}$ exsists and can be written as a polynomial of $T$ with degree less than n.I get stuck here and don't know how to move on.
Thank you for your answering.

If $F$ is a finite field, then for $n$ larger than the size of $F$, there cannot be pairwise different $\lambda_i$’s, so the question doesn’t make sense. Did you want $F$ to be infinite?

The question does make sense in your special case, @Pranay: the statement is then vacuously true.

@AnneBauval ah yes, of course.

The requirement is equivalent to $\prod_i(T-\lambda_iE)=\prod_i(T-\lambda_iE)\sum_ic_i(T-\lambda_iE)^{-1}$, which means precisely that
$$
f(x)=\prod_i(x-\lambda_i) - \sum_ic_i\prod_{j\ne i}(x-\lambda_j)
$$
is an annihilating polynomial of $T$. Since the characteristic polynomial $p$ of $T$ is a degree-$n$ monic polynomial that annihilates $T$ (Cayley-Hamilton theorem), it is natural to try to pick $c_k$ that makes $f$ equal to $p$.
As $f$ and $p$ are monic polynomials of degree $n$, the degree of $f-p$ is smaller than $n$. Hence $f$ is equal to $p$ if their values agree at $n$ different points. So, it suffices to choose $c_k$ such that
$$
p(\lambda_k)=f(\lambda_k)=-c_k\prod_{j\ne k}(\lambda_k-\lambda_j)
$$
for each $k$. Clearly this is possible by setting $c_k=-\frac{p(\lambda_k)}{\prod_{j\ne k}(\lambda_k-\lambda_j)}$.

Let us multiply both sides by $\prod_j (T-\lambda_j E)$. Then the equation becomes
$$
\sum_i c_i \prod_{j\ne i} (T-\lambda_j E) = \prod_j (T-\lambda_j E).
$$
The each term on the LHS is a polynomial in $T$ of degree $n-1$. We can replace the $T^n$ term on the RHS with lower degree terms using the characteristic polynomial of $T$ via Cayley-Hamilton theorem. This gives us a polynomial in $T$ of degree at most $n-1$ on both sides. Comparing the coefficients gives $n$ linear equations in $n$ variables $c_1,\ldots,c_n$, i.e., $A c = b$, where the entries of the $n\times n$ coefficient matrix $A$ are given by
$$
A_{ki} = \sum_{S \subseteq [n]\setminus\{i\}:|S|=k}~\prod_{j\in S} \lambda_j.
$$
where $k=0,\ldots,n-1$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, and $[n]:=\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Here, I use the standard convention that the empty product is defined as $1$. More explicitly,
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
\sum_{j\ne 1} \lambda_j & \sum_{j\ne 2} \lambda_j & \cdots & \sum_{j\ne n} \lambda_j\\
\sum_{j_1<j_2;j_1,j_2\ne 1} \lambda_{j_1}\lambda_{j_2} & \sum_{j_1<j_2;j_1,j_2\ne 2} \lambda_{j_1}\lambda_{j_2} & \cdots & \sum_{j_1<j_2;j_1,j_2\ne n} \lambda_{j_1}\lambda_{j_2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\prod_{j\ne 1} \lambda_j & \prod_{j\ne 2} \lambda_j & \cdots & \prod_{j\ne n} \lambda_j
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
All we need to show is that this matrix is invertible.
It is clear that $\det A$ is a polynomial in $\lambda_i$'s and each $\lambda_i$ appears with degree at most $n-1$. Moreover, when $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$, the first two columns are equal, so $\det A$ vanishes. Therefore, $\lambda_1-\lambda_2$ is a factor of $\det A$. Similar arguments imply that
$$
\det A \propto \prod_{i<j}(\lambda_i-\lambda_j).
$$
But the RHS has degree $n-1$ in each $\lambda_i$, so the proportionality factor is simply a constant. I don't yet have a proof that this constant is nonzero, but assuming it is, it follows that $A$ is invertible (because all $\lambda_i$'s are pairwise different) and there is a solution for $c$.
Note that we didn't actually need $\lambda_i$'s to be different from the eigenvalues of $T$. I think this information is needed only to go back to the original formulation of the problem.
